# Typescript error where function parameter can be of type string or another type

Tags: typescript

I need help fixing a typescript error that I do not fully understand. The function accepts a single argument `option` that can either be a `string` or another object type. Below is an example screenshot from the typescript playground.

[image]

When I tried accessing the `name` prop, I expected to get it from the `Details` type. However, it throws an error. Why is it causing an error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you please explain why your function parameter is an interface ?

Comment: TypeScript does not let you access the name prop because it could be a string, and strings do not have a name prop. You can fix this by checking if the option is not a string before using the name prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [reading the guide on Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#defining-a-union-type).

Essentially, you're only able to access properties that exist on all types within a `Union` type. `string` does not have a `name` property, so `option.name` doesn't make any sense if the option is a string, and the compiler won't allow that because **you haven't proven if it's a string or a Details object**

You could do something like this:

```js
if(typeof option !== "string") {
  console.log(option.name)
}
```

Because in that case, the compiler can *infer* that Option is a `Details`.

You can also use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to check if something is a certain type.

tl;dr; read the link at the start of this answer ([this one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#defining-a-union-type)) about Union types, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here, option can be either string or Details, so it fix this error while accessing name you need to make sure that the type of option variable isn't string.

```ts
const testFun = (option:Test['option']) => {
  if (typeof option === "string") return;
  
  console.log(option.name);
}
```